# Evaluate strength of enemies with class level

Tags: pathfinder-1e

How can a player evaluate the strength of an ennemy? My players encounter guards that were far less powerful than them but fled because they looked strong. Can they make a skill check for evaluating CR of enemy with class levels?

Comment: Related: [How to deal with overly cautious players?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/21717/4398)