# How do I get players to care about the Lost Mines of Phandelver adventure?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, story, lost-mine-of-phandelver, plot-hooks

I'm going to be running LMoP with a group mostly new to D&D. How can I get them to care about the hook enough to be interested in the story? I tried it previously with another group, but they just didn't feel like they had a reason to care about the story (they made their own characters).

This time, I'm going to do a proper session zero (but still let them make their own characters), but I need advice on ways to get them to be interested in the hook.

I'm also fairly new to DnD and don't know how to make a good hook.

I had an idea of making the party go with Gundren and Sildar to Phandelver, but get knocked out by the Goblins on the path (making them a larger raiding party). When the party wakes up, they are robbed of some gold, and Gundren and Sildar are gone. Would that work?

Comment: Are the players using the pre-made characters, with their built in plot hooks, or custom made characters? What about for your previous group?

Comment: Fascinating--I'd have sworn we had a question on this, but [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/77147/23970) about the side-quests is the closest I could find.

Comment: Related: [How to handle players who make unmotivated characters](/questions/77056), [How can I encourage my players to give me plot hooks?](/questions/35879), [How can I get players to stop ignoring or overlooking the plot hooks I'm giving them?](/questions/142852)

Comment: Augie, do the linked questions above answer your query?

Comment: Hi Augie, I like this question, because one of my groups that I ran this for once also found the story and plot hooks very underwhelming. Unfortunately, and especially with the addition at the end, this question seems to be a rather "opinion-based" question; what that means is that the format of this site doesn't really suit brainstorming requests or similar, since there's no way to tell which answer is "best" when each answer is just an opinion. If brainstorming is what you're after, though, your question might be better suited to a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/35259)?